# Como printar um elemento de um lista de listas em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, estrutura-de-dados

Tenho uma lista de listas, assim: [ ('nome1',tamanho1), ('nome2', tamanho2)]

Quero printar apenas o nome de cada lista, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
l = [('nome1', 1), ('nome2', 2)] # Cria lista de tuplas
for t in l:
   print(t[0]) # Imprime o primeiro elemento da tupla
```